# Pandas - what is the most efficient way to filter DataFrame using pandas.Series.all

Tags: pandas, indexing

Consider the code below -

```
import pandas as pd
data = []
val = 0
for ind_1 in range(1000):
    for ind_2 in range(1000):
        data.append({'ind_1': ind_1, 'ind_2': ind_2,
                     'val': val})
        val += 1
df_mi = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(['ind_1', 'ind_2'])
```

which creates the DataFrame `df_mi` with MultiIndex-

```
In [90]: df_mi                                                                                       
Out[90]: 
                val
ind_1 ind_2        
0     0           0
      1           1
      2           2
      3           3
      4           4
...             ...
999   995    999995
      996    999996
      997    999997
      998    999998
      999    999999

[1000000 rows x 1 columns]
```

Now I want to filter the rows by applying some condition on all values for each `ind_1` -

```
In [116]: bool_filter_ind_1 = (df_mi['val'] < 999997).all(level='ind_1')                             

In [117]: bool_filter_ind_1                                                                          
Out[117]: 
ind_1
0       True
1       True
2       True
3       True
4       True
       ...  
995     True
996     True
997     True
998     True
999    False
Name: val, Length: 1000, dtype: bool

In [118]: ind_1_filtered = bool_filter_ind_1.index[bool_filter_ind_1]                                

In [119]: ind_1_filtered                                                                             
Out[119]: 
Int64Index([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,
            ...
            989, 990, 991, 992, 993, 994, 995, 996, 997, 998],
           dtype='int64', name='ind_1', length=999)
```

The result is correct but `df_mi.loc[ind_1_filtered]` is relatively slow -

```
In [120]: timeit df_mi_filtered = df_mi.loc[ind_1_filtered]                                          
4.73 s ± 10.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [121]: df_mi_filtered                                                                             
Out[121]: 
                val
ind_1 ind_2        
0     0           0
      1           1
      2           2
      3           3
      4           4
...             ...
998   995    998995
      996    998996
      997    998997
      998    998998
      999    998999

[999000 rows x 1 columns]
```

Is there a faster way to perform the same filtering?

Comment: use iloc instead; it should be significantly faster as there is no conversion from labels to index. if you do have labels, then i would suggest using ind_1_filtered.get_indexer(ind_1_filtered), to get the actual indices, then pass into iloc

Comment: @user2309803 - Is `df_mi.iloc[ind_1_filtered.get_indexer(ind_1_filtered)]` correct? I tested it with sample data and it return `[999 rows x 1 columns]` instead `[999000 rows x 1 columns]`

Comment: @jezrael correct, I just see that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

First idea is `invert` mask to `df_mi['val'] >= 999997)` and get all `ind_1` indices for less like threshold and filter original indices of first level by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) for mask and filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
def new(df_mi):
    lvl0 = df_mi.index.get_level_values(0)
    return df_mi[~lvl0.isin(lvl0[(df_mi['val'] >= 999997)].unique())]

In [240]: %timeit (new(df_mi))
51.5 ms ± 555 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Another idea is use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) for mask and again filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
In [241]: %timeit df_mi[(df_mi['val'] < 999997).groupby(level='ind_1').transform('all')]
97.3 ms ± 1.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Original solution:

```
def orig(df_mi):
    bool_filter_ind_1 = (df_mi['val'] < 999997).all(level='ind_1')  
    ind_1_filtered = bool_filter_ind_1.index[bool_filter_ind_1]
    return df_mi.loc[ind_1_filtered]

In [242]: %timeit orig(df_mi)
11.2 s ± 405 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```